# How does regex {m,n}? work in re module in Python?

Tags: python, python-re

I am using the re module in python to search for certain patterns in texts and extract a sample of those.

Imagine I have this string variable:

```
a = "ON EST III PT4N0M0 EST"
```

I want to extract this pattern T_N_M, being '_' any group of characters and having as few distance as possible between this T, N and M.
I used the findall fuction as:

```
matcher = re.findall('.{1,5}T.{1,10}?N.{1,10}?M.{1,5}', a)
print(matcher)
```

where the '?' after {1,10} indicates I want as few repetitions as possible of the preceeding character (which is '.', that corresponds to any character). However, executing this command I get the result:

```
['ON EST III PT4N0M0 EST']
```

when what I really want to get is:

```
['III PT4N0M0 EST']
```

Answer (score 0):

Even with non-greedy matching, the regex engine will return the leftmost possible match. If you want to restrict your pattern, try e.g.

```
>>> re.findall('.{1,5}T[^TN]{1,10}?N[^NM]{1,10}?M.{1,5}', "ON EST III PT4N0M0 EST")
['III PT4N0M0 EST']
```

I can only guess what actual constraints you have on your matches, but this hopefully at least nudges you to clarify your requirements for yourself.